# Django CMS results in 500 error if debug is false and only in editing mode

Tags: django, django-cms

I have a django-cms 3.0.2 instance in production. Debug is off, apache configured, allowed_hosts set. I can browse the pages, log into admin etc. Everything works fine except one thing:

If I try inline editing (.../?edit) then I get a 500 Server Error.

Apache Error log is silent. My logger give me the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 137, in get_response
    response = response.render()

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 82, in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context)

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 140, in render
    return self._render(context)

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 840, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 854, in render_node
    return node.render(context)

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 123, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 840, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 854, in render_node
    return node.render(context)

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/classytags/core.py", line 106, in render
    return self.render_tag(context, **kwargs)

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sekizai/templatetags/sekizai_tags.py", line 76, in render_tag
    rendered_contents = nodelist.render(context)

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 840, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 854, in render_node
    return node.render(context)

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/classytags/core.py", line 106, in render
    return self.render_tag(context, **kwargs)

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com/cms/templatetags/cms_tags.py", line 632, in render_tag
    content = render_to_string('cms/toolbar/toolbar.html', context)

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 164, in render_to_string
    return t.render(Context(dictionary))

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 140, in render
    return self._render(context)

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 840, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 854, in render_node
    return node.render(context)

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/templatetags/i18n.py", line 171, in render
    output = self.nodelist.render(context)

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 840, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 854, in render_node
    return node.render(context)

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 203, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render(context))

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 155, in render
    return self.render_template(self.template, context)

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 137, in render_template
    output = template.render(context)

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 140, in render
    return self._render(context)

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 840, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 854, in render_node
    return node.render(context)

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/templatetags/i18n.py", line 171, in render
    output = self.nodelist.render(context)

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 840, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 854, in render_node
    return node.render(context)

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 897, in render
    return render_value_in_context(output, context)

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 875, in render_value_in_context
    value = force_text(value)

  File "/source/ComGo/comgo_regional_de_com/comgo_regional_de_com_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 116, in force_text
    raise DjangoUnicodeDecodeError(s, *e.args)

DjangoUnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 12: ordinal not in range(128). You passed in <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0xa795930c> (<class 'django.utils.functional.__proxy__'>)
```

However if I temporarily turn on debug, then I can edit as well.

So whats going wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: Try opening toolbar.html and saving it in Unicode UTF-8 format.

Comment: I saved the file again in utf-8 - but the error remains unchanged.

Comment: I could fix it however I still wonder about the implementation. My error setup was debug=false; template_debug=debug, thumbnail_debug=debug. By accident I only changed the latter two to true and my problem disappeared. Having debug off while template and thumbnail debug on in production - is for me a hack and not a solution. Why the behaviour is not clear to me...

Comment: @rollinger: did you ever isolate the problem itself?